# Convert CGPathRef to NSBezierPath

Tags: macos, nsbezierpath, cgpathref

In Apple docs they give you code of how to convert NSBezierPath to CGPathRef. I need to convert the other way around, from CGPathRef to NSBezierPath. UIBezierPath has a property called cgPath so if I was working on iPhone that would not be a problem, but I'm working on MacOS.

This must be an old question, and I was sure to find an answer on Internet but no luck. Could be I'm missing something. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Old question but I'm sure this will still be helpful for others. (You didn't specify Objective-C or Swift; this is an Objective-C answer.)

You can convert a `CGPathRef` to an `NSBezierPath` using `CGPathApply()` with an applier function callback that translates the `CGPathRef` points to `NSBezierPath` points. The only tricky part is the conversion from `CGPathRef`'s quadratic curves to `NSBezierPath`'s cubic curves but [there's an equation for that](http://fontforge.github.io/bezier.html):

> Any quadratic spline can be expressed as a cubic (where the cubic term is zero). The end points of the cubic will be the same as the quadratic's.
>
> ```
>  CP0 = QP0
>  CP3 = QP2
> ```
>
> The two control points for the cubic are:
>
> ```
>  CP1 = QP0 + 2/3 * (QP1-QP0)
>  CP2 = QP2 + 2/3 * (QP1-QP2)
> ```
>
> ... There is a slight error introduced due to rounding, but it is usually not noticeable.

Using the equation above, here's an `NSBezierPath` category for converting from `CGPathRef`:

**NSBezierPath+BezierPathWithCGPath.h**

```
@interface NSBezierPath (BezierPathWithCGPath)
+ (NSBezierPath *)JNS_bezierPathWithCGPath:(CGPathRef)cgPath; //prefixed as Apple may add bezierPathWithCGPath: method someday
@end
```

**NSBezierPath+BezierPathWithCGPath.m**

```
static void CGPathToBezierPathApplierFunction(void *info, const CGPathElement *element) {
    NSBezierPath *bezierPath = (__bridge NSBezierPath *)info;
    CGPoint *points = element->points;
    switch(element->type) {
        case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint: [bezierPath moveToPoint:points[0]]; break;
        case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint: [bezierPath lineToPoint:points[0]]; break;
        case kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint: {
            NSPoint qp0 = bezierPath.currentPoint, qp1 = points[0], qp2 = points[1], cp1, cp2;
            CGFloat m = (2.0 / 3.0);
            cp1.x = (qp0.x + ((qp1.x - qp0.x) * m));
            cp1.y = (qp0.y + ((qp1.y - qp0.y) * m));
            cp2.x = (qp2.x + ((qp1.x - qp2.x) * m));
            cp2.y = (qp2.y + ((qp1.y - qp2.y) * m));
            [bezierPath curveToPoint:qp2 controlPoint1:cp1 controlPoint2:cp2];
            break;
        }
        case kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint: [bezierPath curveToPoint:points[2] controlPoint1:points[0] controlPoint2:points[1]]; break;
        case kCGPathElementCloseSubpath: [bezierPath closePath]; break;
    }
}

@implementation NSBezierPath (BezierPathWithCGPath)
+ (NSBezierPath *)JNS_bezierPathWithCGPath:(CGPathRef)cgPath {
    NSBezierPath *bezierPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    CGPathApply(cgPath, (__bridge void *)bezierPath, CGPathToBezierPathApplierFunction);
    return bezierPath;
}
@end
```

Called like so:

```
//...get cgPath (CGPathRef) from somewhere
NSBezierPath *bezierPath = [NSBezierPath JNS_bezierPathWithCGPath:cgPath];
```